# How to pass value into ng-if after ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Purpose**

I am trying to get admin and customer show in different stages, admin can post the data after clicking the `toggleShowDiv()`, which allows customer to see the data.

**Question**

How to pass `!isAdmin()` into `ng-if`? Currently, I am only getting `isAdmin` as default.

Is able to post it into table TD by TD (row by row)? not sure, I am writing the correct code here.

**My thought**

Can I use `ng-if` to each single `TD = isAdmin()` or `!isAdmin`, and control by a click function?

```
$scope.showDiv = isAdmin();

$scope.toggleShowDiv = function (auction) {
  var title = 'text.......';
  var text = 'are you sure?';

  ConfirmModal(title, text, function () {
    $scope.showDiv = !isAdmin() ;
  });
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-if="showDiv">
  <tbody class="auction-group" ng-repeat="a in foos">
    <td ng-if="isAdmin()">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleShowDiv()" />
    </td>
</div>
```

**Update**

`isAdmin()` is just a function that passed from the backend.

```
function isAdmin() {
  return !!($aScope.currentUser && $aScope.currentUser.isAdministrator);
}
```

Please note: the question is not about the `isAdmin()` function, it works fine. What I want to do is to use a click function to show and hide the table row.

Comment: have you defined isAdmin()?

Comment: Its just a user. so isAmin () = only access by admin , ! isAdmin() = other users

Comment: how do you know on the first hand that someone is admin?

Comment: Can you add the code of the function `isAdmin` pls ?

Comment: yep, sure its updated, as I mention the isAdmin() = hide_to_other_users , if I assign this to the table, only admin can c it. and if I assign it as !isAdmin , other users can c it but use can't not.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to let a control display if a user is an admin when the page loads (without a user click)?

Comment: yes, thats absolutely correct

Comment: @Fenici from your comments I can somewhat figure out what you want. Can you edit the HTML to show where the content is?

Comment: I tried to offer an answer to your question but I think I may have misunderstood your requirement.  Reading this again, it *seems like* you are trying to say that you have two people looking at your page at the same time, and you want the changes one user makes to change what the other user sees, is that correct?

Comment: @Claies, much appreciated for your respond, your answer is somewhat close. Yes, The page itself container 2 users admin or No-admin(users). admin controls the view before the data release to no-admin.  so I am trying to use click function to control the view. if the button is check, and it can view by both admin and No-admin, vise-versus.

Comment: I was starting to head in the right direction before I removed my answer;  Essentially, instead of checking the status of the user, you need to check the status of the data object;  i.e. each object needs to have some sort of flag, like `a.publiclyVisible` or some such.  then, you can use `ng-if="a.publiclyVisible || isAdmin();`.  The admin user can then update the object's `publiclyVisible` flag, and save the data to the server, where the next time someone loads the data, they will be able to see it.

Comment: yep, that's the correct ideas. I will give a try later. is the flag =a which is ng-repeat="a in foos"

Comment: the flag should be a property of `a`, which is each `a` in `foos`, yes.

Comment: what actually isAdmin() function returns

Comment: @ Anil Shrestha  isAdmin() returns a access right. isAdmin= only Admin

Comment: @Fenici, let me know if my answer helps, if it doesnt address a concern, let me know ill fix it

Comment: I have to chalk this up to bad requirements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at this. Here you have 2 users online at the same time, dude1 (admin) and dude2 (non admin). You can toggle the display from the admin side for the non admin side by having a call to the back end that continuously checks if the display is valid or not. For putting a toggle on the table rows you need to just add the `ng-if` to the `<tr>` elements.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller("controller", function($scope) {
    $scope.dude1 = {admin: true, name: [{name: 'A+', country:'India', publish: true}, {name: 'A', country:'Unknown', publish: true}]};
    $scope.dude2 = {admin: false, name: [{name: 'A+', country:'India', publish: true}, {name: 'A', country:'Unknown', publish: true}]};
    
    $scope.toggler = (index) => {
        $scope.dude1.name[index].publish = !$scope.dude1.name[index].publish;
    };
    
    $scope.names = (dude) => {
        return dude.name;
    };
    
    setInterval(() => {
        /**
         * Any backed function to get and repopulate the data.
         * Update the value of publish from the server. I'm just using
         * the other guys data. But you should fetch it from the server.
         */
        $scope.dude2 = valfromServer();
        // console.log($scope.dude2, $scope.dude1);
    }, 2000);
    
    var valfromServer = () => {
        return {
            admin: false,
            name: $scope.dude1.name
        };
    };
    
    $scope.publish = (dude, index) => {
        return dude.admin || dude.name[index].publish;
    };
    
    $scope.isAdmin = (dude) => {
        return dude.admin;
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.0" data-semver="1.6.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
    <span>Admin Panel</span>
    <div>
        <table style="width:40%">
            <tr ng-repeat="x in names(dude1)" ng-if="publish(dude1, $index)">
                <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.country }}</td>
                <td>{{ $index }}</td>
                <td><button ng-click="toggler($index)" ng-if="isAdmin(dude1)">Publish</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    
    <hr>
    <span>Non admin panel</span>
    <div>
        <table style="width:40%">
            <tr ng-repeat="x in names(dude2)" ng-if="publish(dude2, $index)">
                <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.country }}</td>
                <td>{{ $index }}</td>
                <td><button ng-click="toggler($index)" ng-if="isAdmin(dude2)">Publish</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer is really close, but what happens is both data are in the same table and the button is in the table > td as well .. that's the part I am struggling to do.

Comment: so do you suggest that i can sperate the table into 2 ? one for admin and another for users ?

Comment: @Fenici, Observe that the table is values are the same for both guys, but the way it renders is different by checking its properties. Run the edited code, perhaps it will be more clear

Comment: ok  i was thinking you are using the different set of data x in names(dude1) and 2

Comment: @AnilShrestha it works as long as the data is refreshed at regular intervals from the back end.

Comment: great. finally you got solution after 9 days

Answer (score 4):

```
<div ng-if="showDiv == true || isAdmin == true">
  <tbody class="auction-group" ng-repeat="a in foos">
    <td ng-if="isAdmin == true">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleShowDiv()" />
    </td>
</div>
```

JS code Let say first any one who enters will be customer

```
$scope.showDiv = false;
$scope.isAdmin = false;
```

now when response comes form backend check the response and change the value of $scope.isAdmin accordingly.

```
if(response == admin){
  $scope.isAdmin= true;
}else{
  $scope.isAdmin = false;
}
```

now in onclick checkbox function

```
$scope.toggleShowDiv = function (auction) {
   var title = 'text.......';
   var text = 'are you sure?';

   ConfirmModal(title, text, function () {
     if($scope.showDiv == false){
        $scope.showDiv = true;
     }else{
        $scope.showDiv = false;
     }

   });
};
```

Comment: Umm , thanks for the respond Anil , I think you miss the point that isAdmin is not equal to true or false. it has value to check the page whether the page is accessed by Admin or not.

Comment: You can check the value and change the value of isAdmin accordingly

Comment: If the page is accessed by admin change it to true else false

Comment: function isAdmin() {
  return !!($aScope.currentUser && $aScope.currentUser.isAdministrator);
}  this is the function i got to check whether isAdmin

Comment: you mean the function returns current user and if the current user is admin or not

Comment: then what is the problem are you not being able to check that the user is admin or not

Comment: admin and user are on the same page, and I am trying to block user to see the information before admin click the button or check the button, but this button is in the table row within the data. This is what essentially what I wanna do

Comment: it's pretty hard to get the idea of it. and I didn't explain clearly in the question, sorry about that

Comment: well if user and admin are in the same page and in same pc or laptop then there is no different between user and admin. if they are in different pc or laptops in same page then you have to use database. for each row you have to save certain value so that which row can be seen by user

Comment: " if they are in different pc or laptops on the same page then you have to use database" this is the case ~ what do you mean by database?

Comment: where is your data foos comming from

Answer (score 2):

Well I think that you should use some var that change according if the user click like $scope.showTable = true /false. But not complety sure about your real need.

Comment: I am trying to let a control display if a user is an admin when the page loads (without a user click) , so the data can only display by isAdmin () , and shows to users.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `ng-if="showDiv"`  use something link `ng-if="obj.showDiv"`

In the controller define `$scope.obj = {};`

The issue is `ng-if` creates its own scope, so always pass data as an object because objects in JS are passed by reference.

Answer (score 2):

I am confused on your question - 
I will suggest few points, i hope it will help you -

1. `ng-if` is a inbuilt directive. You can use it on any DOM element. You can control it by using attribute or function, only need to pass `Boolean` attribute to this directive. Eg: 
   `ng-if="showHideAttribute"` or `ng-if="functionNameWhichReturnBoolean()"`
2. Scope - if you are clicking on button/checkbox/ng-click applied element is available in the same scope of applied ng-if directive then no problem. Otherwise you need to use service or observers (on/emit/broadcast) or `rootScope` then only it will work.
3. I hope you are receiving `isAdmin = true/false` from backend in your function. So, i am thinking this is the problem of scope.

Comment: what i am trying to do is set a the same page into different stage 1. admin 2. not admin . Admin user is able to control the view(show table row or hide table row) by ng-click function to no admin user. if that make sense to you ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

ng-if = "isAdmin == false"

Comment: No , isAdmin has a value which identifies the access right. whether they are admin or users?

Comment: OK Agreed!! You can do something like
$scope.showDiv = !$scope,showDiv;

Answer (score 1):

You're *really confusing* me, but if I understood correctly, it is something like this you want?

First things first, your HTML is truely horrible, parts of tables in divs? Don't do that...

Secondly, don't hack kabout with the isAdmin to toggle things.
`isAdmin` should only be used to check if a user is an admin.

You can however create another variable that instantiates to the same value, and use that one to toggle stuff.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  this.content = 'This is some unpublished content, only the admin can view, unless you\'ve now gone and publish it.';
  this.isPublished = false;
  this.isAdmin = false;
});
```

```css
/* Put your css in here */

textarea,
label,
button {
  display: block;
  margin: 15px 15px 0 0;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>

<div ng-app="plunker">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as $ctrl" ng-init="$ctrl.isAdmin=false">
    <article>
      <section class="content">
        <section ng-if="$ctrl.isAdmin || $ctrl.isPublished">{{ $ctrl.content }}</section>
        <section ng-if="!$ctrl.isAdmin && !$ctrl.isPublished"><pre>-- no published content found --</pre></section>
      </section>
      <section class="admin-only" ng-if="$ctrl.isAdmin">
        <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="$ctrl.isPublished"> publish article</label>
      </section>
    </article>
    <hr />
    <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="$ctrl.isAdmin"> is admin</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**edit:**
You're still confusing me, but does this come closer to what you want / need?

Comment: what I am trying to achieve is to stage the data before its release to the user. so the purpose of the checkbox is to release the data to users (!isAdmin). and when the checkbox is unchecked. the data only can view by admin.

Comment: so when the checkbox is checked, the data can view by admin and user both. I have the admin and user on the same page and same table.

Answer (score 1):

What i understand is, "When admin trigger some action i.e. ng-click, user should be able to see that data/changes."

If this is the case, consider following:

1. I'm damn sure that this is not going to happen on the same machine.
   Admin will be using the application on his machine from where it'll
   do some action i.e. ng-click will gets fired and some data will gets
   changed on server.
2. Now there will be (n) number of users using the application from
   their machines. How they will get to know about the change which admin has made?
3. In such scenario, when there is changes on server and
   client(browser) should be aware of that we make use of socket.io,
   which listens to events from server and refreshes itself when there
   is some changes on server state or we can say, when admin has
   triggered some action i.e. ng-click.

Let me know, if you have any queries.

Thanks